# CM11: Nexus 10 boots forever

Tags: samsung-nexus-10, cyanogenmod

My Nexus 10 boots forever. I did (according to the cm-wiki):

1. Root it
2. Flash Clockworkmod-Recovery with fastboot
3. Flash CM11 with sideload
4. Flash Boot.img with fastboot

Now my Nexus 10 is stuck at the boot animation.

Any ideas?

---

I tried to `wipe dalvik cache` in advanced Menu in cwm. When I afterwards choose "show log" I get the following error:

`mount: mounting /dev/block/platform/dw_mmc.0/by-name/userdata on /data failed: Invalid arguemnt
W:failed to mount /dev/block/platform/dw_mmc.0/by-name/userdata (File exists)`

May theres ist the problem?

---

I flashed stock rom, and this works like a charm. Then I tried to install cm again and twrp. But, twrp tells me, that /data can't be mounted. I tried in twrp (Advanced, Terminal Command):

`# mount /data
mount: mounting /dev/block/mmcblk0p9 on /data failed: Invalid argument`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I had to format the partition /dev/block/mmcblk0p9 by hand (with twrp).

I can't remember the command exactly - but more or less it was:

`mkfs -t ext4 /dev/block/mmcblk0p9`

Answer (score 2):

Boot into recovery and get a shell (e.g. `adb shell` on the PC connected via USB). Then format the userdata partition:

```
mke2fs -t ext4 /dev/block/platform/dw_mmc.0/by-name/userdata
```

Afterwards, simply reboot and it should work fine.

The reason why this is necessary is simply (thanks to @utkanos in #cyanogenmod for explaining it): When unlocking the bootloader using `fastboot oem unlock` it erases all data but doesn't create a proper filesystem.

Comment: Solved my issue with Nexus10. Could not wipe the device, so was stuck in bootloop. Did not know it was due to this.

Answer (score 1):

Try to enter cwm recovery and do a full wipe factory reset. Wipe both dalvik cache under advanced section and cache.

Comment: @Tobias If you have any important information on yiur phone make a backup then download and flash that rom via zip file (if there is an option) and restore your data

Comment: @Tobias the log says that system can't mount a partition where the installation is located so there is a serious problem

Comment: I don't have any important data... There's no worry.

Comment: I flashed the stock rom again, and this worked like a charm. I think, this is a good sign...

Comment: Good now do you want a cm11 rom?

Comment: @Tobias if yes go here https://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=manta and download the first rom. When you completed tell me

Comment: Yes, I want. And, I have it. I tried the last snapshot release. I use sideload to install it and fastboot to flash boot.img. And, it is booting forever (see above).

Comment: Ya but i didn´t wanted for you to install it via sideload i wanted to install via zip option in "install zip from the sd card menu".

Comment: Glad you make it :)